# Can regular expression be written in /private/etc/hosts file

Tags: windows, mac, networking, hosts-file

```
abc.local
xyz.local
dumy.local
www.google.com
local.testserver.net
```

....

Can we write some kind of regular expression or Rule in "hosts" file to redirect certain domains ending .local to certain ip address. like using above domains.

```
192.168.0.10 *.local
192.168.0.1 www.*
192.168.0.100 local.*.*
```

// Hosts file path on Mac OS X is /private/etc/hosts and in windows c:/windows/system32/drivers/etc...

Comment: [Mac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS), not [MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address), please.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible.

See these related questions:

- [Wildcards in a hosts file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138162/wildcards-in-a-hosts-file)
- [Setting up wildcard domains on local host (OS X 10.5)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684558/setting-up-wildcard-domains-on-local-host-os-x-10-5)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in the hosts file.  For acceptable syntax see this:  [/etc/hosts file](http://linux.die.net/man/5/hosts)